# Problem of adjusting column width - multicolumn sideway table

Tags: tables, rotating

Below is my minimum working code that I put together to create a multi-column sideway table in `LaTeX`. But my problem is I can't reduce the distance between  "1996-1998" and "1998-2000" so that the last column ("2010-2012")will not go over the page.
Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Thanks much!

My code is:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{8pt}


\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}[ph!]
\caption{Summary statistics of XXX}



\centering

\begin{tabular}{lllllllllllllllllllllllllllllllll}\\
\vspace{0.3cm}\\
%\toprule

\multicolumn{2}{l}{$HRS$ $wave$}& \multicolumn{2}{l}{$1996$-$1998$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$1998$-$2000$}
 & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2000$-$2002$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2002$-$2004$}& \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2004$-$2006$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2006$-$2008$}
& \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2008$- $2010$}  & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2010$-$2012$} \\
%\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(r){4-5}\cmidrule(r){6-8}\cmidrule(r){9-11}\cmidrule(r){12-14}\cmidrule(r){15-17}\cmidrule{18-19} \cmidrule{21-23}\\

%& $IRR$  && $IRR$  && $IRR$ &&& $IRR$ &&& $IRR$ &&& $IRR$&&& $IRR$ $IRR$\\
\midrule\\
\vspace{0.1cm}
$XXXX$ && $1098$-$624$ && $1931$-$819$ && $1808$-$553$ && $1501$-$165$ &&$1741$-$176$ && $1737$-$172$ && $1675$-$177$ &&$1744$-$217$\\
\hline
 $Childhood$ $health$ &&& $1.29$\\
 $Childhood$ $SES$ &&& $1.08$\\
$Mother's$ $education$ &&& $1.04$\\
$Father’s$ $education$ &&& $1.12$\\
$Financial$$help$ &&& $1.02$\\


$Adult$ $SES$\\



\bottomrule
\end{tabular}


\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! I counted 32 columns. Even in sideways mode this is most probably too wide!

Comment: Unrelated comment: It looks like you're using math mode (`$ .. $`) to get italics. Don't do that, use `\textit{this is italic}`.

Comment: Why 33 columns when you actually need only 9 ?

Comment: @AboAmmar - It's not clear whether the table contains 9 or 17 columns. At any rate, there are certainly far fewer than 33 columns. :-)

Answer (score 2):

Your table is not actually too wide, but you are using 33 columns when only 9 are required. Using a slightly smaller font size (`\small`) as well as shrinking the inter-column space (`\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}`) can achieve what you want. To get the italic letters use `\textit{..}` and don't use math form `$ .. $`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{8pt}
\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[ph!]
\setlength{\tabcolsep}{4pt}
\caption{Summary statistics of XXX}
\medskip
\small \centering 
\begin{tabular}{*{9}l}\\ %\toprule
\textit{HRS wave} & {1996-1998} & {1998-2000}
 & {2000-2002} & {2002-2004}& {2004-2006} & {2006-2008}
& {2008- 2010}  & {2010-2012} \\
%\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(r){4-5}\cmidrule(r){6-8}\cmidrule(r){9-11}\cmidrule(r){12-14}\cmidrule(r){15-17}\cmidrule{18-19} \cmidrule{21-23}\\
%& IRR  & IRR  & IRR & IRR & IRR & IRR& IRR IRR\\
\midrule\\
\vspace{0.1cm}
\textit{XXXX} & 1098-624 & 1931-819 & 1808-553 & 1501-165 &1741-176 & 1737-172 & 1675-177 &1744-217\\
\hline
 \textit{Childhood health} & 1.29\\
 \textit{Childhood SES} & 1.08\\
\textit{Mother's education} & 1.04\\
\textit{Father’s education} & 1.12\\
\textit{Financialhelp} & 1.02\\
\textit{Adult SES}\\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}    
\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you set fontsize to `\footnotesize`  and reduce the the value of `\tabcolsep`, it fits the margins. I'm not sure about the placement of the 4th column.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{booktabs, array, caption}
\usepackage{multicol}
\setlength\columnsep{8pt}

\begin{document}

\begin{sidewaystable}[ph!]
  \caption{Summary statistics of XXX}
  \centering\renewcommand\tabcolsep{4pt}
  \footnotesize
  \begin{tabular}{ >{\itshape}l*{22}{l}}%
    %\toprule
    \multicolumn{2}{>{\itshape}l}{HRS wave}& \multicolumn{2}{l}{$1996$-$1998$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$1998$-$2000$}
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2000$-$2002$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2002$-$2004$}& \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2004$-$2006$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2006$-$2008$}
    & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2008$- $2010$} & \multicolumn{2}{l}{$2010$-$2012$} \\
    %\cmidrule(r){2-3} \cmidrule(r){4-5}\cmidrule(r){6-8}\cmidrule(r){9-11}\cmidrule(r){12-14}\cmidrule(r){15-17}\cmidrule{18-19} \cmidrule{21-23}\\
    %& $IRR$ && $IRR$ && $IRR$ &&& $IRR$ &&& $IRR$ &&& $IRR$&&& $IRR$ $IRR$\\
    \midrule\addlinespace
    XXXX & & $1098$-$624$ & & $1931$-$819$ & & $1808$-$553$ & & $1501$-$165$ & & $1741$-$176$ & & $1737$-$172$ & & $1675$-$177$ & & $1744$-$217$ \\
    \midrule
    Childhood health &&& $1.29$\\
    Childhood SES &&& $1.08$\\
    Mother's education &&& $1.04$\\
    Father’s education &&& $1.12$\\
    Financial help &&& $1.02$\\
    Adult SES \\
    \bottomrule
  \end{tabular}
\end{sidewaystable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Some suggestions and observations:

- Don't use math mode to italicize letters -- the spacing around all letters will be wrong. If you do need to generate italic text, use `\textit{...}` instead.
- To reduce the space between columns, don't modify the parameter `\colsep`; instead, modify the parameter `\tabcolsep`.
- AFAICT, your table contains 17 columns, not 30+.
- In the case of your table -- assuming an A4 paper size and standard margins -- I believe a combination of using `\footnotesize` and reducing the value of `\tabcolsep` somewhat (done via the use of a `tabular*` environment) should let the table fit inside the textblock.

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{rotating,booktabs,caption}

% set page size and margins
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=1in]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{sidewaystable}
\footnotesize
\captionsetup{size=small} % match size of surrounding material
\caption{Summary statistics of XXX}

\setlength\tabcolsep{0pt}  % let "tabular*" figure out spacing

\begin{tabular*}{\textwidth}{ l @{\extracolsep{\fill}} *{16}{c} }\\
\toprule
HRS wave& 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{1996--98} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{1998--2000} & 
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{2000--02} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2002--04}& 
 \multicolumn{2}{c}{2004--06} & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2006--08}& 
\multicolumn{2}{c}{2008--10}  & \multicolumn{2}{c}{2010--12} \\
\cmidrule{2-3}   \cmidrule{4-5}   \cmidrule{6-7}   \cmidrule{8-9}
\cmidrule{10-11} \cmidrule{12-13} \cmidrule{14-15} \cmidrule{16-17} 

& IRR  && IRR  && IRR && IRR && IRR && IRR&& IRR && IRR\\
\midrule
\addlinespace
XXXX && 1098-624 && 1931-819 && 1808-553 && 1501-165 &&1741-176 && 1737-172 && 1675-177 &&1744-217\\
\midrule
Childhood health   &&& 1.29\\
Childhood SES      &&& 1.08\\
Mother's education &&& 1.04\\
Father's education &&& 1.12\\
Financial help     &&& 1.02\\
Adult SES\\

\bottomrule
\end{tabular*}

\end{sidewaystable}
\end{document}
```